# Is my application exiting due to a memory leak or privacy violation?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I am developing a simple application, which requires a user to register to login to the application.  I am using firebase as my database.  The application loads as expected and displays correctly, yet as soon as I enter the required registration details instead of uploading the data to firebase and loading the login page the application crashes.

Looking at Logcat it appears I have a memory leak or I am in violation of privacy rules, however being relatively new to this I'm not entirely sure where I am going wrong.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText userEmail, userPassword;
    private Button register;
    private TextView login;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupUiViews();

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (validate()){
                    // Upload data to the database.

                    String user_email = userEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_password = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupUiViews(){
        userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegistered);
    }

    private boolean validate(){
        boolean result = false;

        String email = userEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = userPassword.getText().toString();

        if (email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter all details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

As requested Logcat below:

```
2020-05-28 12:56:32.695 5462-5462/com.devops.ignite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.devops.ignite, PID: 5462
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.shayledevops.ignite.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: What errormessage do you get?

Comment: add your logcat to this

Comment: I have added Logcat as requested.  It seems my original assumption was inaccurate as it turns out I am receiving a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize `firebaseAuth` before calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` on it.

Something likeL

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupUiViews();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); // this line is new

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validate()){
                // Upload data to the database.

                String user_email = userEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String user_password = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    ...
```

Comment: Thank you Frank van Puffelen, I didn't think I needed to initialise it so that makes perfect sense.  However, having now done that I am still receiving a null pointer exception :(